# Yii CHtml::radioButton ----adding labels

Tags: php, jquery, yii, radio-button

I have this code where I'm using CHtml::radioButton, but I want to add labels inline after each button.

I tried radioButtonList, got the labels working, but then I could not get the default 'no' to be checked.

I want to reveal a text-field upon the 'yes' button being checked.

```
<tr id="MULTI_PART_VIEW" style="display:none">
    <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('MULTI_PART_PO#')); ?></th>
    <td>
      <?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($model,'MULTI_PART_VIEW',array('size'=>120,'maxlength'=>64,'value'=>$model->MULTI_PART_VIEW)); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th><?php echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('MULTI_PART_PO#')); ?></th>
    <td>
        <?php echo CHtml::radioButton(
            'MULTI_PART_PO',
            true,
            array('value'=>'no', 'uncheckValue' => null),
            array('onclick' => "$('#MULTI_PART_VIEW').show();")
        )?>
        <?php echo CHtml::radioButton(
            'MULTI_PART_PO',
            false,
            array('value'=>'yes','uncheckValue'=>null)
        ); ?>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Did you even try to look into Yii documentation?

Comment: @Jurik  Really, dude?  OF COURSE!  Why do you bother?

Comment: [first google result](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/39266-checkbox-label/) leads me to [Yii documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#activeLabelEx-detail) - that's why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to render label after each input you can use this approach:

```
<?php echo CHtml::radioButton('MULTI_PART_PO', false, array('value'=>'yes', 'id'=>'radioButtonId', 'uncheckValue'=>null)); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::label(CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('MULTI_PART_PO')), 'radioButtonId', ); ?>
```

Also you can wrap your radio button in `<label>...</label>` as follows:

```
<?php 
    echo CHtml::openTag('label');
    echo CHtml::radioButton('MULTI_PART_PO',false, array('value'=>'yes', 'id'=>'radioButtonId', 'uncheckValue'=>null)); 
    echo CHtml::encode($model->getAttributeLabel('MULTI_PART_PO'));
    echo CHtml::closeTag('label');
?>
```